# Matrix where block is left as identity matrix

Tags: matrices, alignment

I want to reproduce the following matrix:

[image]

However, the best I am able to create is:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & I_{n-2}  \\
    0 & 0 
\end{matrix} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you replace `0 & ... & 0` with `0\dots0` in row 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1      & 1      & 0\dots0 \\
0      & 0      &         \\
\vdots & \vdots & I_{N-2} \\
0      & 0      & 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pNiceMatrix} 
1      & 1      & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0      & 0      &         \\
\vdots & \vdots & \Block{2-3}{I_{N-2}} \\
0      & 0      
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]